# Trigger controller action when selecting item in table with KODataTable MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'm presenting data in a table by calling an Action(that returns a list in Json) through an AJAX call.

*Output:*
http://imageshack.com/a/img673/3484/zxZIqy.png

What i would like to do is to make each user (rows in table) linkable to an edit page (*Admin/Edit/Id*). Either by simply clicking on them, or by having an Edit-link at the end of each row.
I don't know how to achieve this. It would be easy with ordinary razor syntax. But this template seams to be nice to work with to achieve this sort of dynamic datatable.

I'm working with a template called [KODataTable](http://mikeallisononline.com/Projects/KODataTable) to make this table with both searching and sorting ability.

***View..***

```
<div id="kodt">
    <div>
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: searchText, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
        <select data-bind="value: selectedColumn, options: columns"></select>
        <button data-bind="click: search">Search</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr data-bind="foreach: columns">
                    <th data-bind="text: $data, click: function() { $parent.sort($index()) }" style="cursor: pointer"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: currentRows">
                <tr data-bind="foreach: $parent.columns, click: function () { $root.selectRow($data); }, css: { 'success': $root.selectedRow() == $data }">
                    <td data-bind="text: $parent[$data]" style="cursor: pointer; text-align: center"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button data-bind="click: firstPage">First</button>
        <button data-bind="click: prevPage">Prev</button>
        Page <span data-bind="text: currentPage() + 1"></span> of <span data-bind="text: pageCount"></span>
        <button data-bind="click: nextPage">Next</button>
        <button data-bind="click: lastPage">Last</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

***Script..***

```
<script>
    var users = new Object();
    $.getJSON("/Admin/GetUsers", function (data) {
        users = data;
        var TableDataVM = new KODataTable({
            columns: ["Id", "Username", "RoleId", "CompanyId", ""],
            rows: users,
        });
        ko.applyBindings(TableDataVM, document.getElementById("kodt"));
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now, it looks like when a user clicks a row, `$root.selectRow($data);` is invoked, which passes the row object's data over to some function in the ViewModel called `selectRow()`.  If this function exists, you could use it to `$.post` the row (representing the `user` object) to the MVC controller in this function, and use the response to redirect to the Edit view.

```
var vm = function() {
    var self = this;
    var selectRow = function(rowClicked) {

        var data = {
           Id = rowClicked.Id,
           Username = rowCicked.Username,
           // etc.
        };

        // post the data to some MVC controller - something remotely like this
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Admin/Edit/' + rowClicked.Id,
            data: ko.toJSON(data),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (result) {
                window.location.href = result.url;
            }
        });
    };
};
```

Comment: I defined an own function for this.. redirectToEdit();. Wich i placed on the td rows click event and added the whole object for that row as argument ($data). I then simply redirect to admin/index along with the id of that clicked row with this function..

var redirectToEdit = function (data) {
    window.location.href = "/Admin/Edit/" + data.Id;
};

Comment: That sounds very similar to the answer I offered.  Did this help you solve your problem, or are you still having an issue?

Comment: Oh indeed @alex. But i solved it before i saw your answer. Sorry for answering so late. And thanks for your contribution!